# What is assigned to a variable if 'grep' doesn't return anything?

Tags: bash, grep

I want to check if a object exist and if it's allready there, then I want to delete the object before recreating it.

I need this for handling android emulators during the build process but it seems like if I can't assign a result of 'grep' to a variable if nothing has been found...?

Here my (not working) example:

```sh
echo "# --> use avdmanager"

# delete existing avd if available
test_avd=$(android list avd | grep test)
if [ ! -z $test_avd ]
  then
    echo "# --> delete old avd"
    avdmanager delete avd -n "test"
fi

# create new avd
```

The scripts stops after `test_avd=$(.....)` if *grep* could't find anything without any error.
Even if I put some quotes around it like `test_avd="$(...)"`, it's just the same.... :(

This version works fine, but I don't really know why. Maybe someone out there has any suggestions?

```sh
echo "# --> use avdmanager"

# delete existing avd if available
if [ ! -z "$(avdmanager list avd | grep test)" ] 
  then
    echo "# --> delete old avd"
    avdmanager delete avd -n "test"
fi

# create new avd
```

Comment: You have to quote parameter expansions, so that if the parameter expands to an empty string, it doesn't simply disappear from the command. `[ ! -z "$test_avd" ]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `grep` returns nothing, the `$test_avd` variable would be empty.  But there's no need for a variable here.

Instead of this:

```
test_avd=$(android list avd | grep test)
if [ ! -z $test_avd ]
```

Use this:

```
if android list avd | grep -q test
```

---

Note:  when variables *are* needed, the `! -z` is also needless; `[ "$test_avd" ]` returns exactly the same result as `[ ! -z $test_avd ]`.

Comment: You want `grep -q` instead of `grep -s`. `-q` ("quiet") keeps `grep` from outputting matches it finds; `-s` ("silent") keeps it from outputting errors about unreadable/nonexistent files. I get 'em confused too. It doesn't help that `--silent` and `--quiet` are both synonyms for `-q`.

Comment: Thx to both of you! :)